# How to define a custom font family for a wordpress blog that will not affect the entire site

Tags: formatting

While my related question on Stack Overflow *should* explain the basic CSS for this once it gets answered, how would I define a custom font family for a wordpress blog that will *only* apply to a <span> and will not affect the site-wide font families being used by the theme on my wordpress site?

> Related: [Creating Useable Custom Font Family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079767/creating-useable-custom-font-family)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

Use this in your header.php

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This gives each page a different class and so you can use CSS to set the font-family for a specific page like so:

```
body.blog span.yourClassName{ font-family:; }
```

Then of course the is also the jQuery solution using the [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function

Comment: Are you saying you want to apply classes to all elements within a specified element, or?

Comment: If you look at the code above closely you will see that the CSS rule selects all span's with a class of .yourClassName within the blog page only.

Comment: marcup, i had old information, you appeared to have edited, so that answers my question.  Thanks!  :)